# Clear Checkboxes and Textboxes in Splitcontainer - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

I'm attempting to clear all the checkboxes and textboxes in the first panel of my splitcontainer but I'm having no luck as nothing seems to happen.

```
private void clearSettingsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control c in splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox)
        {
            ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
        }
        else if (c is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)c).Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Are you sure the controls that should be cleared are placed in Panel1 of splitContainer1?

Comment: Absolutely, I originally had the code clear the checkboxes in the whole form itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your code is pretty OK, there should be another problem like wrong panel or more likely there would be another container in your panel, like a GroupBox, which in that case (another container) you should iterate through that container.

In case you have a container inside the panel a simple code could be like this:

```
            foreach (Control control in splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls)
        {
            if (control is GroupBox)
            {
                foreach (Control child in (control as GroupBox).Controls)
                {
                    if (child is CheckBox)
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)control).Checked = false;
                    }
                    else if (child is TextBox)
                    {
                        (control as TextBox).Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But if you want to write a more general code, you should check for each container, i.e. GroupBox, Panel etc.

Comment: I think that this is most likely the problem considering all my checkboxes and textboxes are within groupboxes. You wouldn't happen to know of any examples that iterate through a container?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, useful to see how it works. On running the code, errors are thrown at the points where it changes the checkbox to false and clears the textbox, any ideas?

Comment: *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

Comment: This shouldn't happen because casting to CheckBox only happens if the control is actually a CheckBox. If you still have problems, please share your code for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (c is CheckBox)
                {
                    ((CheckBox)c).Checked = false;
                }
                else if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)c).Text="";
                }
            }
```

Comment: statement -> `there is no such function as ((TextBox)c).Clear();` is wrong there is method `Clear()` used to Clear the `TextBox`.